# Word usage of "Ramification"

Tags: word-usage

Is the below sentence has a repetition of words:

> The negative ramifications that result from absent
>   parents are obvious.

The confusing raised in my mind due to the fact that "ramifications" is also a synonym of a "result from", and the writer used both the words in a sentence.

Can I write below way?

> The negative ramifications from absent parents are obvious.

Do they convey the same meaning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As James K said, the most common usage is "ramification of something".

Can you say:

> The negative ramifications from absent parents are obvious.

Yes you can. But it is more commonly expressed as "ramifications of", as others have already said.

You are correct in that you have spotted a somewhat tautologous use of "ramifications that result from". Is it illogical or wrong? Not quite, but sort of. Negative ramifications can literally result from another action, even though they are themselves (almost invariably) negative outcomes of another action. It's a kind of recursive sentence. But I very much doubt the author of the sentence thought of any of that. I think they just picked a clumsy preposition.

If, for some reason, I really wanted to say "from" rather than "of" (and I can't think of a reason why you would), I personally would word it like this:

> The negative ramifications **arising from** absentee parents are obvious.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying it.

Can i also write like below?

>The negative ramifications that arise from absentee parents are obvious.

Comment: Yes. Absolutely.

Answer (score 0):

We would normally use "ramifications *of* something".

It is a slightly odd word. Its base meaning is "branching out", but it is almost always used metaphorically, to mean "unintentional consequences", particularly those that will cause difficulties. It tends to be used in political discussions (since the *ramifications* of a political decision are often a matter of debate).